# Android Bluetooth connection With MAC Address

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is it possible to create a Bluetooth connection with only a MAC address of the module?

Example of my code

```
private static String address = "00:15:FF:F2:19:5F";
BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
BluetoothDevice device = BluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
new ReadBluetoothTask().execute(new Object[] ReadBluetoothTask.test.read, device});
```

But i think something's wrong with the `getRemoteDevice()` method.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe that's because you are trying to call `getRemoteDevice` as a static method and you need `adapter.getRemoteDevice` instead

Comment: Did you receive an error? If so, please [edit] your question to add the full details of that error.